# How to check if property contains more than one value?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that runs through a list of computers and checks if there is more than one Network Interface.  (It will list IP addresses for each computer)

How can I have the script alert me if there is more than one IP address given for each computer?
I am wanting to differentiate between computers that have 1 IP address and more than 1 IP address.  (I'm trying to find computers that have more than one NIC)

I am having trouble in the ***ForEach ($p in $proc) {***

```
#Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name | Out-File C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\change_dns\computers.txt

$computers = gc "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\change_dns\computers.txt"

ForEach ($comp in $computers) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -EA 0 -Quiet) {

        $proc = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName $comp | Format-Table -Property IPAddress
        ForEach ($p in $proc) {

            #if $p contains more than one IPAddress, write-host or notify that the computer has more than one IP
            #else if $p contains only 1 IPAddress, output that the computer only has one IP

        }

    }

  #   else {
  #  "$comp is Offline."
  #  }
}
```

Comment: Change `Format-Table -Property IPAddress` to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress`. Then you should be able to inspect `$p.Count` inside the inner loop

Comment: if ($p.count -gt 1) {do this}